# How to bulk toggle 'Fuzzy' translations in Loco Translate without 3rd party tools?

Tags: wordpress, language-translation

I have a lot of strings marked as Fuzzy in loco translate for Wordpress.
Is there a way to bulk toggle these translations into accepted translations within Loco translate itself?

Thus without using 3rd party tools like Notepad++ with "Find & Replace" and then regenerate the translations

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to edit via notepad++ for instance translation *.po file and bulk remove frase using Ctrl+H:

#, fuzzy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You're right, but that wasn't my question in the first place. My question was: How do I (bulk) toggle the state of translation strings inside Loco Translate. I updated my post to be more clear